# DB query from a belongs_to relationship

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-postgresql

I have a model: Animal

```
belongs_to :owner
```

I have a model: Owner

```
has_many :animals
```

Owner has a boolean attribute `active`

```
def self.not_active
  where('owner.active == ?', false)
end
```

The above code does not work for some reason.  I've tried lots of things around it, but keep getting errors.  When calling something like `Animal.first.owner.active` I get back either true or false, but the database call must be different...

For clarification I want the Animals for which their owner is not active.  I don't want to do the opposite call though (Starting with the owner db and checking active and returning animals) because of calls I'm linking together off of Animal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
def self.not_active
  includes(:owner).where("owners.active = ?", false)
end
```

When referencing a model in pure SQL, as you are doing so above, you need to use the table name, not the singular model name. Thus, *owners*, not *owner*.

A clearer style would be:

```
def self.not_active
  includes(:owner).where(owners: {active: false})
end
```

Rails AREL will take care of referencing the active attribute in the query correctly, and you don't have to worry about the exact table/model name.

Comment: this is close, but still didn't work.  also i don't think I can use the second part, because I have active on multiple models

Comment: Sorry, I missed another problem: SQL uses a single equals sign for testing equality, not double-equals. Try my first example above, which I've edited for this correction.

Comment: nah that's still not quite correct, I was gonna submit another answer, but if you just add this I'll accept `includes(:owner).where(...)`

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't understand that you wanted the Animals with inactive Owners. I should have read more carefully. I'll update my answer.

Comment: perfecto, i'll try the second part so it looks better, but the first definitely works!

Comment: And, a note on the edited second example, you can use the where(hash) style while avoiding column reference ambiguity via nested attributes, like `where(owners: {active: false})`, ensuring that you won't be checking for active on a different object.